How do you automatically run the "react-native" emulator?

In Desktop
(npm start > a)
(The emulator turns on automatically)


npm start video
terminal(?) image
emulator image

in Laptop
(emulator -avd name_of_emulator > npm start > a)
(Before running "npm start", must turn on the emulator)


I want to use a laptop like a desktop
I want to use a laptop like a desktop
terminal(?) image
I also want to know the program name of the image
(CMD X, Azure X, PowerShell X ...)
